# Stripe Automatic Charges vs Subscriptions

Tags: stripe-payments, payment

This might be something that is really simple, or might not be possible yet all. This is why I am looking for some feedback here before I do anything wrong.

```
x = initial amount being charged
y = minimum balance that should be there on their account
```

In my application, I want to charge my customer a `x` amount when they signup and have it stored as their `account balance` on my application. I am programming my application such that when their `balance < y`, another amount `x` is charged to their account again, and the calculated total is stored as their `account balance`.

As I cannot do this with subscriptions because I wont be doing this after a certain interval of time, but after the balance is less than some amount. This should be possible with charges, with all the conditional algorithm that I am writing.

Is this even allowed?

Comment: What's the real question here? You should ask your legal department whether this is allowed, or Stripe's customer service.

Comment: It looks like you are referring to a billing threshold. You could explore 
1) Metered Billing in Stripe (https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/metered-billing/thresholds)
2) Or you don't need to use Stripe billing, but build your billing logic yourself where you would save a card to customer, simply charge the customer when their balance in your system runs low. (https://stripe.com/docs/sources/customers)